# API root shows "down for maintenance" page

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, maintenance

Normally going to the root of a site API (e.g. http://api.stackoverflow.com/) shows a help page about the API, but for at least the last day or two it's been showing the "site down for maintenance" page:

[image: Screenshot of the SO "down for maintenance" page]

This seems to happen on all the sites, including SE betas. I'm not sure if this is considered an official feature (and the [direct help route](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help) still works), so maybe it was just removed silently, but the down for maintenance page seems an odd choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An adjustment was made to our load balancer to address this.  Thanks for pointing it out.